# Change Visible Month in Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using .net 4.6.1, I'm doing a calculation on the backend to determine when a customer can select an order date, depending on their weekly invoice day. The calculation is working correctly as is the SelectedDate portion, however, when SelectedDate happens to fall within the *following* month, my calendar isn't automatically advancing to show that month by default, it always displays the current month regardless. What am I doing wrong?

```
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        DayOfWeek invoiceDay = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        DateTime nextMonday = GetNextWeekday(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), DayOfWeek.Monday, invoiceDay);

        if (e.Day.Date < nextMonday)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            Calendar1.SelectedDate = nextMonday;
            Calendar1.VisibleDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        }
    }

    public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, DayOfWeek day, DayOfWeek _invoiceDay)
    {
        int daysToAdd = ((int)day - (int)start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

        if (_invoiceDay > DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
        {
            return start.AddDays(daysToAdd);
        }
        else
        {
            return start.AddDays(daysToAdd + 7);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I just needed to a separate method for the initial calendar setup and call that on page load instead of trying to call it all from the DayRender event. The updated code is below:

```
    private DayOfWeek logDay = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
    private DateTime nextMonday;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarSetup();
    }

    private void CalendarSetup ()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            logDay = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
            nextMonday = GetNextWeekday(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), DayOfWeek.Monday, logDay);
            Calendar1.SelectedDate = nextMonday;
            Calendar1.VisibleDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        }
    }

    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.Date < nextMonday)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        }
    }

    public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, DayOfWeek day, DayOfWeek _logDay)
    {
        int daysToAdd = ((int)day - (int)start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

        if (_logDay > DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
        {
            return start.AddDays(daysToAdd);
        }
        else
        {
            return start.AddDays(daysToAdd + 7);
        }
    }
```